# Display content if there is a div with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form that I have iframe that I have to use from another company that I have no control of changing. My visitors are having a hard time understanding the form, and I want to add instructions, but It is hard cause the form had different "pages" or steps and I want to show a paragraph of instructions for that specific step only.

I know it might be a long shot but below is an example of the form and what I want to do.

```
<!-- SHOW ONLY IF ID PAGE1 HAS THE CLASS OF CURRENT-PAGE -->
<div class="my-content">My Content</div>

<!-- SHOW ONLY IF ID PAGE2 HAS THE CLASS OF CURRENT-PAGE -->
<div class="my-content">My Content</div>

<!-- SHOW ONLY IF ID PAGE3 HAS THE CLASS OF CURRENT-PAGE -->
<div class="my-content">My Content</div>

<!-- SHOW ONLY IF ID PAGE4 HAS THE CLASS OF CURRENT-PAGE -->
<div class="my-content">My Content</div>

<!-- THIS IS THE FORM -->
<div class="form-name">
   <div class="current-page" ID="page1"> Page 1 questions </div>
   <div class="page" ID="page2"> Page 2 questions </div>
   <div class="page" ID="page3"> Page 3 questions </div>
   <div class="page" ID="page4"> Page 4 questions </div>
</div>
```

When I go to the next page, it changes the class of the div so page 2 is not the current page and new content is displayed. I want my divs to ONLY show when the div class is "current-page" for that page.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/has or http://api.jquery.com/is should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

Use $.eq(), $.index(), $.show() and $.hide()

```
var content = $('div.my-content').hide();//get all and hide
var i = $('div.current-page').index();//get index of the current
content.eq(i).show();//show selected index
```

OR inline

```
$('div.my-content').hide().eq($('div.current-page').index()).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When changing pages, you can do this:

```
var currentID = $(".current-page").attr('id');
var page = currentID.substr(4); // skip over "page" prefix
$(".my-content").hide();
$(".my-content").eq(page-1).show();
```